# Points in the cartesian plane

Tags: geometry, polygons

> **Moderator Note:** At the time that this question was posted, it was from an ongoing contest. The relevant deadline has now passed.

In the $xy$ plane, suppose  $M_{i,j}=\{(x,y)\mid i\le x\le j\}$.  For $i= 1,2,3,\ldots, 2012$, color $M_{i,i+1}$ red if $i$ is even and blue if $i$ is odd. For a convex polygon $P$ in the plane, let $d(P)$ denote the fraction of its area that is red. Consider polygons that lie completely in the region $M_{0,2013}$ and that have at least one vertex on each of the lines $x=0$ and $x=2013$. What is the minimum value of $d(P)$ over all non-degenerate convex polygons of this type?

Comment: is there a picture

Comment: No... am not sure how to draw one.